# How to use a value from asynchronous ajax

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

Here is my code:

```
function getTitle(url) {
    var urlToGet = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Ftitle'&format=json";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlToGet,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            var result = JSON.stringify(data);
            if(JSON.parse(result).query.results !== null) {
                return JSON.parse(result).query.results.title;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It uses [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) to get the title of the given url. However, `getTitle("http://www.google.com")` returns `undefined`, because it is an asynchronous process. So I've scoured the Internet for ways to solve this, and truly, I saw a lot of discussion but no real solutions. Can someone lay out clearly how I can solve this? (Note: I am unable to do anything server-side)

Thanks!

Comment: "Asynchronous AJAX"? Is there any other kind? :-) Reminds me of PIN number and ATM machine.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to pass a callback to your `getTitle` method...

```
function getTitle(url, callback) {
    var urlToGet = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Ftitle'&format=json";
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: urlToGet,
       async:false,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            var result = JSON.stringify(data);
            callback(JSON.parse(result).query.results.title);
        }
    });
}
```

And call it like this:

```
getTitle("http://www.google.com", function(title) {
    alert(title);
});
```

Comment: Ok, cool, this works. But I have another question: is there a way to set a variable equal to `title`? It's not working for me.

Comment: @KristySaulsbury It should work as long as `JSON.parse(result).query.results.title` does.  Are you sure that's the correct way to parse the result?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the parsing works, but I can't set a global variable equal to `title`. See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hnp46/1/).

Comment: I had a silly syntax error in the link in my previous post. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hnp46/2/) is a corrected version, and the global variable is `undefined`.

Comment: If you just want `title` in the global scope, that's easy enough: http://jsfiddle.net/Hnp46/4/.  The problem is that `async` doesn't work with JSONP.  Whatever you need to do with `title`, have to put that logic inside the callback block.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it this way:

```
function getTitle(url) {
    var title = "";
    var urlToGet = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Ftitle'&format=json";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlToGet,
        async:false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            var result = JSON.stringify(data);
            if(JSON.parse(result).query.results !== null) {
                title = JSON.parse(result).query.results.title;
            }
        }
    });
  return title;
}
```

I've added `async:false` to options and title variable which will be set in success callback. This way getTitle will return title like a regular function, but it will stop execution of any other scripts (and may cause freezing interface, if I'm not missing something) untill request is finished.

The only other option is to do what you need with that title in success callback (with callback function like in another answer here or by placing required code in success callback function directly). Hm. But according to jquery docs:

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support
>   synchronous operation.

So there is only one option)

Comment: I tried `async: false` but I still get undefined when I call `alert(getTitle("http://www.google.com"));`.

Comment: You have a cross domain request and dataType:"jsonp", so async won't work. The only option is to do something like `if(JSON.parse(result).query.results !== null) {
                alert(JSON.parse(result).query.results.title);
            }` in success callback

Comment: Well that's not very useful if I want the computer to handle it all. i'd have to copy-and-paste the result.